# Action-Reaction pair in case of rocket accelerating in space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I understand Rocket works on Newton's 3rd law. So there has to be action-reaction pair acting on two different bodies. 
I know rockets accelerate in space, where there is nothing. So now I want to know those action reaction pair that keeps the rocket accelerating.

Specifically I want to know which part of the rocket (which physical component/structure/fuels/gases?   ) is giving **action** on which other part/components (this part cannot be air, since it is in space) and in turn which other part is giving **reaction** and on which part of rocket?

I am trying to identify this pair. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: The rocket forces its exhaust out at high velocity, the exhaust then reacts and forces the rocket in the opposite direction

Comment: @JimtheEnchanter Exactly which component of rocket Forces the exhaust ? And if the exhaust is responsible for "Reaction" , then my question is , does the exhaust remain the contact with that component (which does the action). I think this contact is required.

Comment: The rocket is open on one side. The exhaust contact the side opposite the open one, pushes off of it, which force the rocket one way and the exhaust the other way. Then it comes to the open side and there is nothing to push off again, so it escapes into space

Comment: Thanks I think I got it now @JimtheEnchanter So can we safely say that: ACTION  is done by exhaust ON the surface of the rocket (opposite to the open end ), REACTION is done by the surface of rocket ON the exhaust  (the exhaust then escapes)

Comment: You can say it however you like, but that is fine and correct

Comment: Do not think in terms of WHICH force is the action and WHICH is the reaction.  That's a weak and misleading concept. Newton said that if one object is experiencing a force due to an interaction with another object then the other object is ALSO experiencing a force in the opposite direction due to its interaction with the first object.  Neither force happens later than the other; both forces exist simultaneously. There is no reaction; it's a linked pair of actions. See this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148516/is-jumping-the-result-of-normal-force-or-action-reaction/168438#168438

Comment: Don't let the names "action" and "reaction" that Newton used fool you. The two are simultaneous in time and there is no implication that one must be active and the other passive. There is neither a point nor a need to sort out which one is the "action". You just need to identify the pair.